# FOR no localstorage não funciona

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Boa noite galera,

O estado do meu LOCALSTORAGE é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu tento fazer isso:

```
for (var post in $window.localStorage) {
                console.log(post);
                var value = JSON.parse($window.localStorage[post]);
                alert(value);
                response.push(value)
            }
```

Ele pega até o atributo length que ja vem com o storage e o atributo key que nao sei de onde saiu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Antes do laço você precisa converter para JSON usando o nome do localStorage com `.getItem`:

```
var json = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cadeira-maia'));
```

Dentro do laço você pega os valores de cada item:

```
var json = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cadeira-maia'));
for (var post in json) {
   console.log(post);
   alert(json[post]);
   response.push(value)
}
```